# How to manually adjust output from model?

Tags: neural-networks, training, pytorch, hyperparameter-optimization

I wonder if it is possible to add manual inference to the output of a model?
For example, I have a model called 'net', and the output value of 'net' is a vector called v = [v1, ... vn]. v is a binary vector. For some reason, I need to manually adjust this output, which means I need to manually flip some 0s to 1s and vice versa.

My question is, is it possible to do so. The reason I have this question are

1. I am new to torch
2. If I manually change the variable.data, even it is doable, I did not do any due adjustments on gradient.

Please enlighten me under the context of PyTorch

Answer (score 0):

It doable of course! Let say you have a Net class with `__init__` and `__call__`, you can do something like this:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.architect = nn.Sequential(...)


    def __call__(self, x):
        out = self.architect(x)
        # Do anythin you want with the prediction in here
        return out
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, the computation graph in PyTorch is guaranteed as long as the operation in there is used by the torch package.

```
# Codesnip example for your case
import torch

# with input x
net = model()
output = net(x) # a binary vector
index = [0, 6, 8] # inverse the value at position (0, 6, 8)
output[index] = 1 - out[index]
```

Further, I don't know why you need to switch it, but switching, clipping, or forcing the output to be some values will harm the gradient, it makes your function non-differential so be careful when you use it.

Lastly, I think this question is more suitable for StackOverflow since you ask for the code editing and the implementation of your idea.

Comment: Yes, what you said is what I am currently trying to deal with. The gradient issue. After I hand-craft the output value from the model, my goal is to guide the gradient so it can converge to my modified output. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: I think with the target vector, the [cross entropy loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) will help achieve the goal without hand-crafting